# Coil of the cooking heater overheats and burn out very often?

Tags: electrical, heater

The coil usually burn at the points circled in red near the power connection. We have 240V electric supply.which the wire support it says.we don't have switch for ON-OFF for heater,we just use hooking.Should I use MCB instead of simple switch will it reduce sparking.
Please don't tell me to increase the number of turn it will definitely reduce the heat of the heater.
Thank you, so much for  your precious time.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: The coil usually burns at the place where it gets connected to main input source.The places which i mentioned in first photo , the coil there is connected then to  input wire which cannot be seen in the photo.I will upload another photo of that

Comment: Looking at the way the coils are mangled near where your red circles are, my guess would be that you've attempted to repair this several times. Each time, I'd guess you've removed some of the burnt out heating coil and that is _reducing_ the resistance, thus allowing it to overheat more quickly. Your best bet at this point may be to completely replace the heating coils with a new one of the proper size or replace the unit entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Too much current is causing the Nichrome coil to overheat.The current can be reduced by lowering the voltage or increasing the resistance . Resistance can be increased by adding to the length of the coil. Localized portions of the coil will overheat if two of more loops are too close so the heat can not escape as fast as necessary.